# How to install and use ffmpeg in Laravel 9 with laradock?

Tags: laravel-8, ffprobe, laradock, ffmpeg-php

I have been spending hours figuring out why I always get an error "Unable to load FFProbe" after installing the FFmpeg package.

1/ I read that I need to add the following line in the .env file

```
 PHP_FPM_FFMPEG=true
```

2/ I restarted apache and run the following command in Terminal (takes sometimes)

```
 cd Sites/laradock
 docker-compose build
```

3/ Then I installed the FFmpeg package in my project

```
 composer require pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg
```

4/ no error, so far... I can see the package is correctly installed in /vendor/pbmedia... but when I try to use FFmpeg in a controller, I get the "Unable to load FFProbe" error

```
use FFMpeg;
...
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open($link);
$frame = $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds($sec));
$frame->save($thumbnail);
```

5/ Should I manually add the following lines in the config/app.php file?

```
in 'providers' ...
ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\ServiceProvider::class,

in 'aliases'...
'FFMpeg' => ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\FFMpeg::class
```

6/ Should I also add a new file in the config folder?

This is so confusing...  please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you install **FFmpeg** itself on your system?